# Moving authentication/authorization to a separate microservice then combining with gateway (zuul + eureka server)

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have 3 microservices - gateway (zuul + eureka), authorization (using jwt and DB based authentication and role assignment), core service (business logic specific microservice). Only requests from authenticated users need to be routed to core service.

How do I configure routes in gateway so that after authetication token is validated, the request gets routed to core service? I have configured /gateway/auth to route requests to authorization. Is there a way to configure /gateway/auth/core so that requests get routed to core after successful authentication / token validation?

I am able to configure when combining authorization with gateway in the same application and configuring before filter. Trying to see if there is a way to keep authorization independent in separate application?